# Unity Forge Networking: client's score doesn't get saved

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, forge

I am having an issue with forge networking.I have finished beginner tutorials and now I wanted to create my own project.It is very simple:I create a local game on one of my devices and client connects.Each of them(client and host) enter their number, and then host's number is displayed to client and vice versa.However, client's number never gets saved and host always sees 0 for client's number, while the actual number is different(the host's number is getting saved and synchronized through the network properly and client CAN read it). I took these steps in creating this project: 1) in forge network contract wizard I have created 2 variables for storing numbers 2) i created a simple script for saving and loading those 2 numbers(this script is attached to an empty game object) :

```c#
 public void UpdateNumber(Text Nmbr)//Button!
 {
     if (!networkObject.IsServer) {
         networkObject.clientNmbr = int.Parse (Nmbr.text);
     } else {
         networkObject.hostNmbr = int.Parse (Nmbr.text);
     }
 }

 public void ShowText(Text text)
 {
     if (networkObject.IsServer ) {

         text.text = "client:" + networkObject.clientNmbr;
     } else {

         text.text = "host:" + networkObject.hostNmbr;
     }

 }
```

I don't see why this works for host but doesn't work for the client

Comment: Because the clients have no network authority to actually write their number to the networkObject on the server. For the clients you have to use `[Command]` function in order to write data on the server.

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for your answer, however I managed to work around this problem.Can you please answer me another question regarding Forge networking? The question is: is it possible that forge networking's NetWorker.EndSession(); function doesn't work for android devices since I have some wird anomaly when testing multiplayer between my android phone and another android phone?However I don't have such problems when testing on PCs.

Comment: Please open a new question